# Is there a way to determine if an HICON contains 100% transparent pixels?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have an image list of icons.  I need to know if an HICON I receive from that image list contains 100% transparent pixels.

How would I accomplish this?  Is there a function that does this or am I going to have to "roll my own"?

Comment: There's no function to do it. Use `GetIconInfo` to get the bitmaps out of the icon and analyze them. (Or `ImageList_GetImageInfo` to get the image data directly from the image list)

Comment: Need more info. This can be done with GDIPLUS quite easily, (you just loop each pixel and check its alpha channel.)

Comment: @EvanCarslake No, no more info is needed. It is a simple question and you've answered it.  I have to "roll my own".  Thanks.

Comment: @Evan: You don't need GDI+. The Windows API calls suggested by Jonathan is all that's really required. And since the OP is using MFC, there's no need to introduce yet another dependency.